# Why is /F typically used with FOR loops even when dealing with non-text files?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I was looking for a batch script to identify the newest file in a directory.  The examples I found all use FOR /F.  When I read the help documentation on FOR, it states that /F opens, reads and processes each file.

Why is /F used in this case?  I've used it with large binary files and the script does not seem to slow down so I do not think each file is actually being opened, etc.

I tried using FOR without /F to do the same job and didn't have any luck.  Is there a reason for that?

For instance:

```
FOR %%I IN ('dir "*.AVI" /B /O:D') DO set newestAvi=%%I
```

does not seem to work.  For some reason, newestAvi is equal to "/O:D'" at the end.

If I use

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('dir "*.AVI" /B /O:D') DO set newestAvi=%%I
```

then things work.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 2):

I think the relevant bit of the help file is

```
Finally, you can use the FOR /F command to parse the output of a
command.  You do this by making the filenameset between the
parenthesis a back quoted string.  It will be treated as a command
line, which is passed to a child CMD.EXE and the output is captured
into memory and parsed as if it was a file.  So the following
example:
```

So, with the /F your command takes the output from

```
dir "*.AVI" /B /O:D
```

and parses **each line** into the command

```
newestAvi=%%I
```

which becomes

```
newestAvi=FileName.AVI
```

for each file in the current directory. The last value assigned is the one that is left at the end of the for commands execution.